# Problema con FVM Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, powershell

al momento de querer instalar fvm, con el pub global activate fvm me da el siguiente error, alguien sabe porque?

```
pub: El término 'pub' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Cáracter 1
+ pub global activate fvm
+ ~~~
 + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (pub:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 + FullyQuialifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolver el error solo agregando el "dart" al principio

```
dart pub global activate fvm
```

Comment: precisamente este es el problema que no reconoce "pub".